# How to display length of word count in vb?

Tags: vb6

So I've been trying for hours to figure out how to display the length of word count in vb. 
For example, if I type in a sentence in a rich textbox and I click a button, I want a form to show up listing the number of one-letter words, two-letter words, three-letter words and so on within that sentence. The number of words of specific length will be outputted in labels, of course.

I found this short code online for word count:

```
dim wordcount as integer

dim a as string() = RichText.Text.Split(" ")

wordcount = a.length
```

However, I'm not sure if this code can be used to get the length of word count. Any ideas of how I can achieve outputting the number of words of a specific length in a label? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. First, please edit your post to format the code correctly. Second, what do you mean you are not sure if the code can be used? Doesn't it work for you? How does it fail? The more specific you describe your problem the better answers you will get.

Comment: Within my form, I have an option that allows the user to determine the number of words within their text (in other words, wordcount). The user types within a rich textbox and after clicking a button, a messagebox shows up with a label containing the number of words. The code above works perfectly for this. The problem I am encountering is with the length of word count. How do I determine how many words of specific length are within the text and then display them in labels? Can the above code be used in conjunction with other code to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read [the help page on formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to find out what I meant when I wrote "format your code"

Comment: No, the code you've posted does not count the number of words of each length. It merely returns the count of words - length of each word is ignored. If you want to count words of each length, iterate through the array elements in `a` after the call to `Split` and count the number of letters in each of them, storing those counts in another array. (And running the code you've posted should clearly illustrate what it returns, without your having to ask here. It's useful to at least put a minimal effort into figuring things out yourself first.)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
Private Sub mnuCount_Click()
    Const DELIMITERS As String = vbNewLine & " !"",.:;?"
    Dim WordCounts(1 To 100) As Long
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim WordCount As Long

    With RTB
        .Visible = False
        .SelStart = 0
        Do
            .UpTo DELIMITERS, vNegate:=True
            .Span DELIMITERS, vNegate:=True
            If .SelLength > 0 Then
                WordCounts(.SelLength) = WordCounts(.SelLength) + 1
                .SelStart = .SelStart + .SelLength
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        .SelStart = 0
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Msg = "Length" & vbTab & "Count"
    For I = 1 To 100
        If WordCounts(I) > 0 Then
            Msg = Msg & vbNewLine _
                & CStr(I) & vbTab & CStr(WordCounts(I))
            WordCount = WordCount + WordCounts(I)
        End If
    Next
    Msg = Msg & vbNewLine _
        & "Grand total:" & vbNewLine _
        & vbTab & CStr(WordCount)
    MsgBox Msg
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Pradnya's code, translated to VB6:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim str As String
Dim splitStr() As String
Dim i As Integer

str = "ABC DEF GHIJ KLMNOPQ"
splitStr = Split(str, " ")
MsgBox "Number of words = " & UBound(splitStr) + 1 & vbCrLf & _
       "Average Length = " & Len(Replace(str, " ", "")) / (UBound(splitStr) + 1)
End Sub
```

I made a few simplifications as well.  There's no need to go through the loop to get the average.  All you have to do to get the length of the whole is remove the spaces and divide by the number of elements in the array.

However, if you want to get a count of the number of words of each length, you'll have to loop through the array, getting the length of each word and storing those values one by one.  Best way to do that is to set a reference to scrrun.dll (Windows Scripting Runtime) and use a Dictionary object to store the values.